# Using a Script to hide rows in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script in an Excel cell. I'm assuming this is a vba script.

{ if (value == "") {hideRow("34");Text_Boiler_Location(2)}

I've done some research and I'm not sure how to hide the active row without hardcoding the row id.  I'm using a form building application that I can build custom reports.  However if I change the form then it will throw of the row id in the script.  I will many of these little scripts and I do not want to change the row id every time I change the form.  So basically I just need to hide the active row if the value is an empty string without hardcoding it.

Comment: I don't think it is VBA code.Nor VB.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Can try below

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden=True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is neither vb or vba.  It is a script created by the form application I use.  They do not have the ability at this time to identify the active row.  It has to be hard coded.  Thanks for everyone's response.